# How to update CSS3 Validator in phpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I have set my CSS level to 3, yet transitions are not being detected by phpStorm.

```
-webkit-transition
```

is a viable property that you can give an element. You can even check it here:
[Transitions W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Also, I am using Level 3 of CSS3. So why does it give an error?
[image]
[image: CSS3 Shown]

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Technically, those are *vendor-specific* CSS properties, so it's not entirely surprising their support is less than stellar. [Known bug about CSS3/vendor specific property support in IntelliJ/Webstorm](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-4698)

Comment: Oh my god, this bug is still there! And `transition` + `animation` are not supported as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**W3C CSS Validator** Inspection in PhpStorm is exactly the same as what you get [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) (the official W3C CSS Validator website), just a local version -- nothing more.

If aforementioned official online tool produces errors/warnings on your code then there is nothing you can do about it except disabling this **extra** inspection (yes, this is additional inspection to PhpStorm's own inspections).

If it's opposite (online tool produces no errors or warnings) then submit a bug report to the [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) and in one of the next releases PhpStorm will have more up-to-date version of this tool.

Answer (score 4):

In Webstorm 8 you can check "Ignore vendor specific CSS properties" under `Project Settings -> Inspections -> CSS -> Unknown CSS Property` and `W3C CSS Validator` in the same category. Custom properties (like `transition`) can be defined (comma-delimited) in `Unknown CSS Property` entry. This is probably applies for PhpStorm as well.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can add the unknown CSS property to custom properties, as shown in the following screenshot (this is the result after you run "Inspection Code..." action):

[image: Add transform to custom properties]

This is a way to train your PhpStorm/WebStorm with the missing CSS properties that you use. I also export my WebStorm/PhpStorm settings so once I fixed these missing CSS properties, i will not have to do it again.

Comment: I was hoping this would help as it seemed promising, but with my `-webkit-box-shadow` attributes, I only get the **Problem synopsis**. The **Problem resolution** part of your screenshot is missing. PHPStorm 7.1.3.